# Cannot save Excel file in Rstudio after binding data

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to save an Excel workbook from Rstudio, in which new data was added, the way I am saving it is with `saveworkbook` from `openxlsx` library, but it gives me the following error:

> Error in zip_internal(zipfile, files, recurse, compression_level, append = FALSE, : zip error: `Cannot add file` [Content_Types].xml`to archive`file383c1b9b6cc7.xlsx`` in file `zip.c:394`

For more background for the excel file, it's size is around `28Mb`.

When I first opened the file in Excel 2007 the software told me that it couldn't read the file, after Excel managed to fix the file its summary was:

> removed part /xl/comments1.xml part with xml error. (comments) load error

I don't know if it was Excel 2007 fix that caused the error Rstudio it gives me,  `zip_internal`.

Also the file uses Excel formulas to extract information of other pages to others.

Does the link between information of different pages contributes to this error?

Below is the code on how i am implementing the program.

```
library(pdftools)
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)
#For smartbind
library(gtools)

#load exel file
old_data<- readWorkbook("file.xlsx", sheet = "Raw");

#bind the new data into old data
new_data<-smartbind(old_data, pdf_refined);

# Write updated data frame to existing worksheet
wb<- loadWorkbook("file.xlsx")
writeData(wb, sheet = "Raw", new_data)

# Save file (with new name for testing purposes)
saveWorkbook(wb, "file.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

- At the end `wb` ends up as `object containing active binding`.
- When Run the `head(new_data)` and `attributes(new_data)`, after applying `data.frame(new_data)` it gives this:

```
Column class mismatch for 'Original'. Converting column to class 'character'.Column class mismatch for 'Bank'. Converting column to class 'character'.Column class mismatch for 'Date'. Converting column to class 'character'.Column class mismatch for 'Original'. Converting column to class 'character'.Column class mismatch for 'Bank'. Converting column to class 'character'.$names
[1] "X1"             "Date"          "Original" "Bank" "X5"            

$row.names
   [1] "1:1"    "1:2"    "1:3"    "1:4"    "1:5"    "1:6"    "1:7"    "1:8"    "1:9"    "1:10"  
  [11] "1:11"   "1:12"   "1:13"   "1:14"   "1:15"   "1:16"   "1:17"   "1:18"   "1:19"   "1:20"  
  [21] "1:21"   "1:22"   "1:23"   "1:24"   "1:25"   "1:26"   "1:27"   "1:28"   "1:29"   "1:30"  
  [31] "1:31"   "1:32"   "1:33"   "1:34"   "1:35"   "1:36"   "1:37"   "1:38"   "1:39"   "1:40"  
  [41] "1:41"   "1:42"   "1:43"   "1:44"   "1:45"   "1:46"   "1:47"   "1:48"   "1:49"   "1:50"  
  [51] "1:51"   "1:52"   "1:53"   "1:54"   "1:55"   "1:56"   "1:57"   "1:58"   "1:59"   "1:60"  
  [61] "1:61"   "1:62"   "1:63"   "1:64"   "1:65"   "1:66"   "1:67"   "1:68"   "1:69"   "1:70"  
  [71] "1:71"   "1:72"   "1:73"   "1:74"   "1:75"   "1:76"   "1:77"   "1:78"   "1:79"   "1:80"  
  [81] "1:81"   "1:82"   "1:83"   "1:84"   "1:85"   "1:86"   "1:87"   "1:88"   "1:89"   "1:90"
[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 802 entries ]

$class
[1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: Without more information there is no way to tell. Replicate the error with a smaller data set  give us the data, the code, and the error messages.

Comment: does it work if you replace new_data with data.frame( new_data ) .  Can you add the head( new_data ) and attributes(new_data) to the questions

Comment: @MatthewR I added the information to the question and adding data.frame it still gives me the same error after data.frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I am facing the same error and could not solve it for my machine, yet.
([my github issue](https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/40))

In some other cases the openxlsx::saveWorkbook() function did not work properly due to a missing temp variable in the system environment. So, may be, it works for you to use Sys.setenv() to set a TMP variable.
Look [here](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/478) for the github issue on that.

Comment: After some research I discovered the problem, the issue is the accent in the name, I also have one in my name. The way I discovered it is using a Mac that I have in my house and in that machine the program works fine.

Comment: @fakestorm99 Thanks fpr your comment!
Any idea, how I can solve the issue?
For me the creation of a new win user account just for a proper R workflow is not a good solution.

Comment: I don't know, the things that i am doing is working in a Apple Mac and trying to do the program in Python to see if this works.